# Python pyqt interface code not running

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I have written a python 3.4 code which uses pyqt4 GUI modules but when i run the module it does not show anything kindly help

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def _init_(self):
        super(Window, self)._init_()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Tallman Server")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("tracking.png"))
        self.home()
    def home():
            btn=QtGui.QPushButton("Quit",self)
            btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
            self.show()


def run():    
         app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
         GUI=window()
         sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the function's name is `__init__` instead of `_init_`. 
Secondly, you have to add the `self` parameter to `home()`.

Those changes will solve your problem.

Modified code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Tallman Server")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("tracking.png"))
        self.home()
    def home(self):
        btn=QtGui.QPushButton("Quit",self)
        btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        self.show()


def run():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI=window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Comment: thanks for the great help am new in pyqt neve knew small errors could make the program not work.

Comment: @tallman: `__init__` and `self` are part of python's object oriented features and have nothing to do with `pyqt`. I suggest you make yourself familiar with classes, e.g. [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) explains it. Otherwise you'll run into similar problems in the future